# Distorted sound in Kubuntu 13.04 64 bit - Sound Blaster X-fi

Tags: sound, 64-bit, kubuntu, alsa, sound-blaster

I am having this problem in Kubuntu. Whenever I play any audio, the sound is fuzzy, echoing, and distorted. I have looked up guides in the official Ubuntu Documentation, but they are for cards with no audio at all... further research reveals that others besides me have difficulty with this card, the Creative! Labs Sound Blaster X-fi SB0460.

I googled deeper into the internets and found a driver pack built by Creative!, which I downloaded, but when I tried to compile it it complained that it could not find my kernel source's version.h - implying that it would probably not work with my kernel, and it is old software that would be nearly impossible to compile with modern software configuration.

What confuses me is that the problem exists with Kubuntu 64 bit, *but not the 32 bit version*.

I also tried older and [newer](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13-rc6-trusty/) kernels but they did not work. Does anyone have any info they can use to point me in the right direction? Anything will help, as I am at a dead end.

Thanks!

lsmod (Kubuntu 32 Bit):

```
Module                  Size  Used by
pci_stub               12550  1 
vboxpci                22896  0 
vboxnetadp             25636  0 
vboxnetflt             27261  0 
vboxdrv               285137  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
parport_pc             27504  0 
ppdev                  12817  0 
rfcomm                 37420  0 
bnep                   17669  2 
bluetooth             202069  10 bnep,rfcomm
binfmt_misc            17260  1 
dm_crypt               22321  0 
kvm_intel             126842  0 
kvm                   376505  1 kvm_intel
snd_ctxfi              87112  0 
dcdbas                 14021  0 
snd_pcm                80890  1 snd_ctxfi
microcode              18286  0 
joydev                 17097  0 
snd_page_alloc         14230  2 snd_ctxfi,snd_pcm
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            25114  1 snd_seq_midi
nvidia              10287297  32 
psmouse                81038  0 
snd_seq                51280  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              24411  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    56485  6 snd_ctxfi,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_device
serio_raw              13031  0 
mac_hid                13037  0 
soundcore              12600  1 snd
i2c_nforce2            12876  0 
lp                     13299  0 
parport                40753  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
pata_acpi              12886  0 
hid_generic            12484  0 
usbhid                 41805  0 
hid                    82666  2 hid_generic,usbhid
firewire_ohci          35292  0 
firewire_core          61718  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              12627  1 firewire_core
pata_amd               13761  0 
forcedeth              61777  0 
sata_nv                23004  3
```

lsmod (Kubuntu 64 bit):

```
Module                  Size  Used by
parport_pc             28152  0 
ppdev                  17073  0 
pci_stub               12622  1 
vboxpci                23194  0 
vboxnetadp             25670  0 
vboxnetflt             23479  0 
vboxdrv               320372  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
bnep                   18036  2 
rfcomm                 42641  0 
bluetooth             228619  10 bnep,rfcomm
kvm_intel             132891  0 
kvm                   443165  1 kvm_intel
joydev                 17377  0 
dcdbas                 14397  0 
snd_ctxfi             107768  2 
snd_pcm                97451  1 snd_ctxfi
microcode              22881  0 
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_ctxfi,snd_pcm
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30180  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61554  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
nvidia              11309139  40 
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29425  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    68876  10 snd_ctxfi,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_device
soundcore              12680  1 snd
psmouse                95870  0 
serio_raw              13215  0 
mac_hid                13205  0 
i2c_nforce2            13020  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                46345  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
vesafb                 13828  1 
pata_acpi              13038  0 
hid_generic            12540  0 
usbhid                 47074  0 
hid                   101002  2 hid_generic,usbhid
forcedeth              66977  0 
firewire_ohci          40103  0 
firewire_core          64508  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              12707  1 firewire_core
pata_amd               14129  0 
sata_nv                31812  5
```

cat /proc/asound/cards (64 bit):

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [XFi            ]: SB-XFi - Creative X-Fi
                      Creative X-Fi 20K1 Unknown
```

cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 (64 bit):

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#0
cat: /proc/asound/card0/codec#0: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Reading [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into), I assumed that you need also post `cat /proc/asound/cards` and `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#0`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that second command. It's added now.

Comment: May be, you should also provide a sample of distorted sound... Who knows, what will be helpful in your case :) Also, I have X-Fi on my home machine too. I will post my config since I get there.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is new driver sheduling. In my X-Fi Surround 5.1 it was the case. 
Find string `#load-module module-udev-detect` in the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, uncomment it if commented (delete #) and append `tsched=0` to the end of the line. Then restart PC.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, unfortunately it did not work. Thanks, though!